# RewriteRule help

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a URL

```
http://test.devsite-1.com/test/tbox/
```

which I want to redirect to

```
http://tbox.devsite-1.com/
```

Rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^tbox\.(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.|)(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/tbox(/.*|)$ 
RewriteRule /tbox/(.*)  http://tbox.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I don't understand why it is not redirecting me to the URL? Please note I need a generalized rule so that if I change `test.devsite-1.com` to `tempo.devsite-1.com` the same should work with the other URL as well.

Comment: modified  RewriteRule (.*)  http://tbox.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]....these is some issue which I am not able to get it...

Comment: If request is coming via `test.devsite-1.com` then `tbox.%{HTTP_HOST}` will generate `tbox.test.devsite-1.com` -- which is obviously wrong (`%{HTTP_HOST}` contains FULL DOMAIN NAME, not just `devsite-1.com`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test/tbox/(.*)$ http://tbox.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect)

```
http://test.devsite-1.com/test/tbox/something-optional
```

to

```
http://tbox.devsite-1.com/something-optional
```

1. It has to be placed in .htaccess file in website root folder (e.g. `http://test.devsite-1.com/.htaccess`). If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.
2. It will only work if request is coming via `test.` subdomain.
3. And it will only work if URL requested starts with `test/tbox/`.

All of the above matches your URL examples.

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between %1 and $1?

Comment: `$1` is a backreference to a first matching group (something between `(` and `)`) in `RewriteRule` pattern (`^test/tbox/(.*)$`) while `%1` is backreference to the same but in `RewriteCond` patterns (`^test\.(.+)$`). More here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/